# Error iterating over groups in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

This code generates errors as indicated:

[image: sample code]

Here is the error message:

[image: error message]

The pop-up definition appears to indicate that the fields marked as undefined do exist:

[image: pop-up definition]

What am I missing?

(Bonus points for telling me why some of error underlines in the code are red while others are blue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that these are groups, so you've got two levels:

```
foreach(var g in groups)
    foreach(var item in g)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
```

When you do a "Group By" in LINQ, you end up with a series of actual "groups", each of which has a `Key` and a series of values. This allows you to perform aggregate functions like `Sum`, `Min` or `Max` on each grouping. If you just want the results with a similar `CountryRegion` to end up together in a flattened collection, you may want to try `OrderBy` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have an `IQueryable<IGrouping<string,Anonymous>>` and therefore need to reference by Key.

```
foreach(var g in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key.FirstName.Trim());
}
```

Comment: This generates a somewhat different error: "'string' does not contain a definition for 'FirstName' and no extension method 'FirstName' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Yeah, the FirstName and LastName don't exist on the key because you're not grouping by those fields.

Comment: @Strip It seems that the Key is a string containing the CountryRegion. But where does 'Key' come from? Is it created automatically by the group/by?

Comment: @casterle: Yes, the key for each group will be the result generated by the `by` portion of the `group ... by ...` clause.